# Using animate in beamer with multiple eps pictures

Tags: beamer, animate

I have a set of 23 pictures that, when combined, give a nice animation. But I don't want to make 23 separate frames for it.

I read that there is an option using the `animate` package but I can't seem to find any example where I could see how to do that (the official `animate` PDF isn't helping :( ).

Could someone make a MWE so that I could see how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at [this related question's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/)

Comment: I almost cried when looking at that XD

I didn't get anything :
Isn't there some easier way to do that? :\

Comment: Read paragraph `Sets of graphics files' on page 5 of animate.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the unanswered. Here is the code directly from the manual of `animate` package as Alexander Grahn pointed out earlier (being the author of the package it seems :). I assume that you images are named `image##.jpg` where the numbers run from 1 to 23 and you want them to play at the fps rate 10

```
\animategraphics{10}{setof23pictures_}{1}{23}
```

should do the trick. Please read the manual for further tweaks.

Comment: This works, I just need to tweak the size of the .eps images :) Thanks ^^

Comment: Again, look into the manual, in particular, look for resizing options `width`, `height`, `depth`, `scale` and for cropping options `bb`, `viewport`, `trim`.